# How to use react-router inside of a method

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to react and react router dom(and javascript in general), and I've been racking my brain and googling all over the place but I can't figure out how to redirect someone in a method like `exampleMethod() {}`. I then call said method in an onClick function on a button. Here's my code for the button:

```
<Button color="secondary" onClick={this.rejoinPrevRoom}>
     Rejoin previous room
</Button>
```

The button is inside a method called renderHomepage which is then called if there is a room code in the state inside the main render function.
The code for rejoinPrevRoom:

```
rejoinPrevRoom() {
    console.log("Debug: A");
    console.log(this.state.roomCode);

    return <Redirect to={`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`} />;
  }
```

It successfully logs a code so there is one but I don't know why it doesn't redirect them.
Any help would be appreciated greatly
Thank you,
Paddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return JSX from a callback handler and expect it to have any effect on what the component is returning to render to the DOM. In this case you can either set some state to conditionally render a `Redirect` component as part of the `render` return, or use the `history` object to issue an imperative redirect via `history.replace` (*not `history.push`*).

```
rejoinPrevRoom() {
  console.log("Debug: A");
  console.log(this.state.roomCode);

  this.props.history.replace(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`);
}
```

If this component is not rendered directly by a `Route` component via the `component`, `render`, or `children` prop, then you can decorate it with the `withRouter` Higher Order Component in order to have the route props injected as props and have the `history` object available as `this.props.history`.

### Update

In order to inject the route props change your `HomePage` export from

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
  ....
}
```

to

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  ....
}

default export withRouter(HomePage);
```

Comment: I've changed it to props.history.replace but I keep getting an error that says "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')" how do i fix this? I've looked at with router but don't really understand how I implement it Thanks for your help

Comment: @Paddyxl I believe this means the component isn't receiving the route props, i.e. no `location`, `match`, or `history` prop, in other words, `this.props.history` is undefined. See the last bit of my answer regarding using the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC to access the route props.

Comment: I think I understand why it's happening but I'm having issues using withRouter. All the docs I've seen say to do `export default withRouter(app)` But I have my code set up as `export default class HomePage extends Component` So I'm not sure where to add withRouter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Paddyxl No worries. So instead of `export default class HomePage extends Component { .....` just declare the class, i.e. `class HomePage extends Component { ....` and then below the class do the default export, i.e. `default export withRouter(HomePage);`. This maintains the default export and will inject the route props of the closest routing context in the React tree. I updated my answer to make this a little clearer since code in comments isn't helpful sometimes.

Comment: @Paddyxl Are you rendering more than one `Router` component in your app? This is a little extra-curricular for your current post here, can you post this as a new question, with the relevant routing code (all of it)? Feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to the new question and I can take a look.

Comment: thank you for all your help as I've managed to get it working now. https://github.com/PaddyCooper08/Block-party that's the link to the GitHub repo of my project. Inside the front-end folder is all the react if you'd like to have a look. I rendered homepage inside app.js in the jsx so I just put that inside a router div and it worked. If fixed the issue with it not redirecting by just using standard js to refresh the web page.

Comment: @Paddyxl I see what you got working. From what I can see, you don't need the `withRouter` HOC in `App.js` since this is the component rendering the `Router` and it doesn't access any route props. This means you can remove the `Router` being rendered in `HomePage`, you only need a single routing context provider. This also means you won't need the `window.location.reload(false);` to reload the app so the outer router picks up the URL change. I also don't see where `HomePage` references route props, so the `withRouter` HOC isn't necessary here either.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React hooks you can redirect like the following:

```
const history = useHistory();

rejoinPrevRoom() {
    console.log("Debug: A");
    console.log(this.state.roomCode);

    history.push(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`);
}
```

If you're using class components:

```
rejoinPrevRoom() {
    console.log("Debug: A");
    console.log(this.state.roomCode);

    const {history} = this.props;
    history.push(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`);
}
```

Comment: React hooks are incompatible with React class components. Function components also have no defined `this` object to reference.

Comment: @DrewReese Did I say they were?

Comment: It's *heavily* implied by your answer that absolutely won't work for the OP unless they convert their class component to a function component, so yeah, basically you did.

Answer (score 1):

If the component is inside a `BrowserRouter`, you can use `history` to do that.

```
rejoinPrevRoom() {
    console.log("Debug: A");
    console.log(this.state.roomCode);

    this.props.history.replace(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`);
}
```